# Is there anyway to initialize an array in C# with a repeated value?

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax, initialization

I've seen similar questions but the answers are all solutions which must be executed in runtime vs on initialization of the variable. To explain what I'm asking for specifically (and what I'm not asking for) take this example:

Say I have an integer array I want to initialize.

```
int[] numbers;
```

Great. But right now it's null. So I'll probably do something like this.

```
int[] numbers = new int[];
```

Now it's an empty array of length 0. But I know exactly how long I want this array to be, so instead I do this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
```

Now I have an integer array with 5 elements that have all defaulted to the default integer, 0. That's fine, but I actually want this array to initialize with all the elements set to -1. Well I could do this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5] {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
```

Cool I have what I want upon initialization....except I actually want the array to have 200 elements....

At this point as far as I've been able to tell my ability to customize the initialized state of this array has reached it's limit. It technically would allow me to manually type out 200 -1's, but obviously I'm not going to do that.

And yes I could use a loop of some kind, the fill method, all those answers in the other questions, but that requires at least one more line of code in an executing block of code. I want to be able to do something like this.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
     int[] numbers = new int[] {-1} * 200;
     public Length => numbers.Length;

     public void SetValue(int index, int value)
     {
          if(index >= 0 && index < numbers.Length && numbers[index] != -1)
               numbers[index] = value;
     }
}
```

Now, it seems clear to me from my research that there simply isn't syntax which allows this. But that is surprising to me. I am hoping that someone has the magic for me. But alternatively, I assume that if something which seems so obviously useful to me can't be done there must be reason for it, and it's probably that it *shouldn't* be done. If that's the case, this is an opportunity for my understanding of programming to deepen if someone explains why I don't actually want to do this even if I could.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `executed in runtime vs on initialization of the variable` Initialization is also at runtime only a const wouldn't be at runtime and Arrays aren't consts. And yes that seems to be a seldom problem. Why should i need a fixed length Array with a fixed starting value. Mostly people won't even use Arrays but other Enumerable types.

Comment: @Ralf, yes I was struggling to determine the correct vocabulary for what I wished to refer to. Initialization is "during runtime". I think what I wanted to say was something more like "executed in method scope" vs "outside of method scope" or something but that doesn't seem to do the trick either. I'm sure there is a term for what I'm looking for that I'm blanking on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [Enumerable.Repeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=net-7.0):

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 5).ToArray();
```

This creates an array containing the element -1 five times.

Comment: I like this. I can use this myself to create an array of shorts initialised to 0x7fff probably.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, I dont think that's possible in C#'s syntax. However, a small workaround you can have is using the Array class, Fill function, which fills the entire array with a single number. This however will still run in runtime.

```cs
    public class YourClass()
    {
        numbers = new int[200];
        Array.Fill(numbers, -1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to add a few extension methods to help filling arrays:

```
public static T[] Fill<T>(this T[] array, Func<int, T> generator)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = generator(i);
    }
    return array;
}

public static T[] Fill<T>(this T[] array, T value) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
    return array;
};
public static T[] FillNew<T>(this T[] self) where T : new() => self.Fill(i => new T());
public static T[] FillDefault<T>(this T[] self)  => self.Fill(i => default);
```

There are some advantages to this, like allowing to fill the array in-place. And should be slightly faster than the linq variant. It should also work on older versions of .net, without `Array.Fill`.

Comment: `Array.Fill` is almost certainly faster, and you can put that inside your second extension method. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.fill?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Charlieface Absolutely, if Array.Fill is available it should be used. But it is already covered by another answer, and as I mentioned, this may be useful on .net framework where neither Array.Fill nor Span.Fill is available.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a method like this:

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int size, T defaultValue)
{
    T[] array = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = defaultValue;
    return array;
}
```

You can use easily:

```
int[] array = CreateArray(200, -1);
```

This is superior to `Enumerable.Repeat` + `ToArray` because it can initialize the array with the correct size, instead of always resizing it in a loop.